# How to handle exception of CompletableFuture get() method

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

I need to to send requests to 3rd party urls so i used `@Async` on `getStatus()` method which returns `CompletableFuture` of `enum` and if `TimeoutException` is thrown i'd like to consider status as DOWN or how to catch `InterruptedException` and `ExecutionException` of each call

```
try {
    firstAppStatus = service1.getStatus().get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    firstAppStatus = ComponentStatusEnum.DOWN;
}
try {
    secondAppStatus = service2.getStatus().get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    secondAppStatus = ComponentStatusEnum.DOWN;
}
try {
    thirdAppStatus = service3.getStatus().get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    thirdAppStatus = ComponentStatusEnum.DOWN;
}
```

I know this code will executed sequentially so how run them asynchronous with this behavior without making changes on client request timeout

Comment: You can do that with ExecutorService and Future objects. What is the type of your service and AppStatus variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
// allow all three requests to run concurrently
CompletableFuture<ComponentStatusEnum> status1 = service1.getStatus();
CompletableFuture<ComponentStatusEnum> status2 = service2.getStatus();
CompletableFuture<ComponentStatusEnum> status3 = service3.getStatus();

// wait for either, the completion of all three or the timeout, whatever comes first
try {
    CompletableFuture.allOf(status1, status2, status3).get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch(TimeoutException|InterruptedException|ExecutionException ex) {
    // no action, as all cases are handled below
}

// get results with fall-backs on timeout
firstAppStatus  = status1.getNow(ComponentStatusEnum.DOWN);
secondAppStatus = status2.getNow(ComponentStatusEnum.DOWN);
thirdAppStatus  = status3.getNow(ComponentStatusEnum.DOWN);
```

First, do not query the results immediately if you want to allow all requests to run in parallel. Then, using `allOf`, you can wait for the completion of all operations with a single timeout.

`getNow` is the right operation to get the result immediately when available or the specified fall-back value if the operation has not completed yet. In principle, it’s possible that the operation completes in the small time window between getting a `TimeoutException` and calling `getNow`, but this should not create any problem for your application logic.

Regarding exception handling, `getNow` behaves like `join()` throwing an unchecked `CompletionException` instead of the checked `ExecutionException` when the underlying operation failed. If you don’t catch it, it gets propagated to the caller, which is the best option if you have no special handling for this case. If the waiting with timeout got interrupted, it will behave just as if you had a smaller timeout; the operations might have finished already or get the fall-back value at `getNow`.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 9 you can use `completeOnTimeout`:

```java
CompletableFuture<ComponentStatusEnum> firstAppStatus = service1.getStatus().completeOnTimeout(ComponentStatusEnum.DOWN, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

More info [here](http://iteratrlearning.com/java9/2016/09/13/java9-timeouts-completablefutures.html).